# Voltage Doubler PWM Circuit

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, high-side

I have the following circuit here, a high-side N-channel MOSFET driver, with gate voltages being generated via the circuit in the middle/NE555 section.

I'm wondering, how does the voltage doubler section actually work? The first 10uF cap charges up with 12v, then is somehow backfed from the 555, effectively doubling the voltage? I'm lost on how the voltage really "adds" up. I've only ever seen voltages increase in series. In my mind, the diode is forcing the 12V through and locking it in, and the charged capacitor is also feeding in "doubling" the circuit. This doesn't really match my understanding as to me, it seems the capacitor and 12V battery are essentially in parallel. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[The circuit in the image below can be found at this link.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDsB0AcYCYCsBTAtJEToE4DMALAjkgAx4BskeOCpsWCWIBeAUGBUiGmAQeAQM0FAYgYVwYXDgrkikHAVI5Y7AEpSmsrSFEhSBlocRHDpaEjYBzELEN5Kdh0ibm2Adx54mQ4T5BHSVI2AGMeexA-CIcnc2hSRNIIGARWSHowHFpyUiRghOTPGMCnNACgg2Lefii0nk5DBHqQ8N45OoF22ODwdBw7aD4KREo8V1IETAtEsGrG0sk0SMqQrzBISR0wUx0QgCcGjuauhYWTJLZD7vAOm73wS69lwx174PnahZvztgATTrgWhRSBMLK+EB-FAAMwAhgBXAA2ABdilMwcDKuCql5KpV0YsqgDsdiTkCIVC4UjUYcsZinKtHk9nITykxVtUAtE0AQGNE1g1asglnwBGSBXSmK4GNiQtCsJsovk9MolZIKixYMVsTpRK8Pl49SBdaq0u4vEhFZVWOy4sVpWqFZJhTiVT0nYSDm6QUwjXhSAImnQOBRfar-QI-U4mJSESi0IiUMSDJYUwMZnNDpbncrs56mcyHdiHeK2Jo8LAxfUK2Jak1jEkoqmEKn4jQRjYWFzlTaorAGObycbJBsth86AMyaT6gT4klEtlF0vl9kpEMkMpiPZVBQcNQBpxbmwJz6hwTGTMkgQVzfss6W6wsqxRAg8Jw0txD5wroFK4De+KdQCiSwI6gaLJYkInrFL2eIMnayiYAB9S8k0qpzOsUH4qC0HPF+dyHns8xjiURF4SROzaOB7RDjRs4-nROFkrOWAhAA9lEB5GMoq50CmeRGL4AzsBxvLgNxZBqCm3AzMg4lMGJ7AVo8RgQGAjbqCgADOACWWnIrCAB2oQoGwymOMwamJCAAAi8LIgAngAOlpADCDmhImbBAA)

[image: Circuit in Question]

Comment: The voltage doubler is much easier to understand if you look at it alone.  Have you visited the wikipedia article on voltage multipliers?  The diodes operate as switches, creating a circuit that operates in two states.  First it fills one set of series capacitors, and when the voltage is reversed the voltage of those now charged capacitors is raised to fill another set of series capacitors in parallel to the first.  Then it returns to the first mode of operation and the second set fills the first set and so on, with each subsequent charge raising the total output.

Comment: If you want a simpler example of how to produce a higher voltage through reconnection, imagine if you simply put two capacitors in parallel and charge them to 5 volts.  If you then connect them in series, they have 10 volts. The Cockroft-Walton voltage multiplier is just an ingenious way to repeatedly make the required connections.

Comment: I understand it with negative voltage swings, but this circuit is done purely on 0-5v square waves. I'm just wondering how the capacitors voltage seems to magically get added just because the diode is there.

Comment: Or is the 555 somehow in series with the capacitors and that's how the voltage is doubling?

Comment: I'm only 70% sure of this because of the way your circuit is arranged, but it looks to me like if OUT pin is held low, that puts 12V across the capacitor through the diode on the left, charging the capacitor to 12V.  When the OUT pin then goes high, it puts 12V in series with the now 12V capacitor.  Causing the diode on the left to block and the one on the right to allow the other capacitor to charge.  You have a 0-12V square wave BTW because your 555 is running off 12V

Comment: Yep I'm pretty sure.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: seems like a lot of fiddling when you could probably use a pchan mosfet or protected driver ic. The opto doesn't look like it adds much value to the circuit.

Comment: I attempted using both PNP and non transistors to let the 24v through to the gate but couldn't really figure it out. The opto made it a lot easier for me to not have to worry about getting the current right or making sure the ground was proper for the transistor. Main reason I didn't go with a pnp transistor was many have rds on values above 10 milli-ohms and I wanted the fet to be able to switch 0-30a loads (maintaining same type of transistor) without any need for a large cooling sink or fan.

Comment: Be careful with a CMOS 555 in this role : its output stage is a bit more fragile than the bipolar ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 555 timer produces a 0-12V square wave on it's OUT pin.  The circuit operates in two states.

First, with OUT at 0V, the diode on the left is forward biased and allows the 10uF capacitor to charge to 12V.  If it is not already charged above 12V, the 50uF capacitor will also charge.

Then when OUT goes to 12V, the now charged capacitor is placed in series with it, producing 24V on the other end of the capacitor.  This reverse biases the diode on the left, and forward biases the diode on the right if it was not already, charging the 50uF capacitor to 24V.

This output is controlled by the optoisolator gate driver.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense to me. For some reason I got to thinking the first diode had something to do with it. Appreciate your insight.

Comment: Yep both diodes are necessary.  Without the first diode the second part of the cycle would backfeed the power supply.

Comment: Understood. This is mostly for an automotive circuit so the 12v would be sourced from a battery, hence the need to generate 22-24v for ideal nmos driving. Is this circuit a good design or is there a better way to do this? As a novice this seems to be the easiest to understand method. Probably not the most cost effective though.

Comment: @ColbyJohnson Isolated DC/DC converters are available that are cheaper, less work and more reliable. There are also high-side drivers designed for automotive use that might be a bit more expensive but offer full protection for that harsh environment.